# The legend.stack doesn't work in tm_layout in R

Tags: r, tmap

The parameter setting doesn't work in `tm_layout`. I've used `legend.stack = "horizontal"`, but the actual legend will not change.

```
library(tmap)
data(World, land)
tm_shape(land) +
tm_raster("elevation", breaks=c(-Inf, 250, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, Inf), palette = terrain.colors(9), title="Elevation", midpoint = NA) +
tm_shape(World, is.master=TRUE) +
tm_borders("grey20") +
tm_layout(legend.only = TRUE,legend.position = c("left","center"),
      legend.stack = "horizontal",legend.text.size = 1.2)
```

I expect the legend to be horizontal, but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`legend.stack` determines the stacking of different legends. You only have one and you should use `legend.is.portrait = FALSE` in the relevant layer to change the stacking within a single legend. In your case, this would be the `tm_raster` layer.

```
tm_raster("elevation", breaks=c(-Inf, 250, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, Inf), 
          palette = terrain.colors(9), title="Elevation", midpoint = NA,
          legend.is.portrait = FALSE)
```

After replacing your `tm_raster` layer with the code above, you should get this:
[image: image of legend]

Comment: Thank you for your help